# JAX-RS nested GenericEntity

Tags: generics, jax-rs, glassfish-4.1

I have a JAX-RS 2.0 service that must return a list of objects of unknown type.
Moreover, I want that this list be nested in a wrapper object.
So, for example, I would like to produce this output:

```
{ "objects": [ {"name":"goofy"}, {"name":"mickey"} ] }
```

If the objects' type were known, this is an easy task.
I have tried in many ways, including using GenericEntity, however I cannot find a solution.

I am using WAS Glassfish 4.1, however I would like the solution were independent from specific WAS.

This is the relevant piece of code of the service:

```
@GET
@Path("{entity}")
public Response find(@PathParam("entity") String entity) {
    Class clazz = someMethod(entity);
    List list = someMethod(clazz);   //return a list of object of clazz
    WrapperClass wrapper = new WrapperClass();
    wrapper.setObjects(list);
    return Response.ok().entity(wrapper).build();
}
```

This code produces as output:

```
{ "objects": [ "object goofy", "object mickey" ] }
```

i.e. the objects are not serialized properly.

Comment: Use Jackson as the JSON provider. This shouldn't be a problem for Jackson. In Glassfish, MOXy is used as the default provider.

Comment: Ok, I tried your suggestion and it works. Even if I don't understand why two implementations of JAX-RS give so different results. Since nobody else has published answers, if you elaborate a little bit I'll accept your answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With Glassfish 4, the default JSON provider is MOXy which is built on top of JAXB. With JAXB, the entity types need to be known beforehand. So the result you are getting is just the value of `toString()`, which is the behavior when the type is not know.

If you want to switch over to using Jackson as the JSON provider, it should work. Jackson does not need to know the type beforehand as it just introspects all the bean properties. To use Jackson in Glassfish, you need to add the dependency to your project and register the `JackonFeature` with the application.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
    <artifactId>jersey-media-json-jackson</artifactId>
    <version>${jersey.version}</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```